# How to create files in SimGrid?

Tags: file, createfile, simgrid

Is it possible to create files in SimGrid?

For example, after some execution program creates file and writes output onto it with `Msg_file_write()`.

For this purpose I tried to use `Msg_file_open()` with nonexistent name expecting that simgrid would create a new file. But compiler only gave me an

```
Segmentation fault.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of MSG_file_write and MSG_file_open is exemplified in https://github.com/simgrid/simgrid/blob/master/examples/msg/io-file/io-file.c
and 
https://github.com/simgrid/simgrid/blob/master/examples/msg/io-storage/io-storage.c

About your specific issue, more than "I got a Segmentation fault" is needed to help you. Do you have any minimal working example that reproduces your issue, or at least some backtrace?